# Referencing self while overloading class methods

Tags: python, default, self

Forgive me if 'overloading' is not the correct term here...

I am trying to do something like this:

```
class Length:

    def __init__(self, length = 0):
        self._length = length

    def twice(self, length = self._length):
        return length*2
```

As you can see, I'm trying to reference `self._length` in the argument of `twice()`.  Python doesn't like this though. I get `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

Is there a good way to assign a default like this and get what I want?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use instance attributes as default arguments of methods.  The methods, along with their default argument values, are defined when the class is defined, but the instance attributes don't exist until later, when you instantiate the class.

You have to do:

```
def twice(self, length=None):
    if length is None:
        length = self._length
    return length*2
```

Comment: Thanks!  This makes sense.  I was hoping I wouldn't have to add even *two* lines of code, but I see that this is probably the best way.

Comment: If you are worried about conservation of line feeds you can use: `return length is not None and length or self._length`. That will leave more line feeds for the rest of us!

Comment: Or just use a classic Mac, and do your part to control the overpopulation of CRs, instead of contributing to the overfishing of LFs.